# How could i disable primary stage when a new stage popup

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I have button that will popup new stage but primary stage wont disable it still can be click so how to disable the primary stage.

This is my code for stage and scene

```
private static final Stage stage = new Stage();
    private static final Stage newstage = new Stage();
    /**
     *
     */

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      scene.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("background.css").toExternalForm());
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
    }

     public void chgScene (String str) throws Exception {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(str));
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
    }

    public void addStage (String str) throws Exception {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(str));
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       newstage.setScene(scene);
       newstage.setResizable(false);
       newstage.showAndWait();
    }

    public void clearStage () {
        newstage.close();
    }
```

If any mistaken so sorry since im just new to Java and i need to create a GUI for my project. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7):

you need to add this:

```
 newstage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
 newstage.showAndWait();
```

see [Modality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html)

Comment: Since my newstage GUI contains a button that process this function
_public void clearStage () {
        newstage.close();
    }_
Then when i reclicked the button in primary stage this error comes
_Cannot set modality once stage has been set visible_

Comment: @Loong you need to call  `initModality` method before to call  `showAndWait ` method .

Comment: You can only call `initModality` once on any `Stage` instance. Since you instantiate it in the initializer and reuse the same instance, you should call `initModality` somewhere that is only executed once, e.g. in `start()`. You should also not make it `static` (that makes no sense at all).

Comment: @Kachna I have solved my problem by using try and catch for intiModality function

Comment: @James_D i use static because im just call all this function from another class if im not using static the function wont work if i clicked the button that call this function _clearStage()_

Comment: `static` means that the field belongs to the class, not to instances of the class. It has nothing to do with accessibility from objects of other classes, which is controlled by `public` and `private`, etc. (It's also a mistake to use `try - catch` constructs for logical processing.)

Answer (score 1):

JavaFx has a various property that you can use, just it depends on the developer how he/she creative on his logic.

```java
mainPane.setDisabled(true);
newPane.showAndWait();
```

Answer (score 0):

Be advised that initModality() is broken and has been for a long time on the Linux platform runtime.

[modal JavaFX stage initOwner prevents owner from resizing, bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243363/modal-javafx-stage-initowner-prevents-owner-from-resizing-bug)

Yes, that post directly refers to initOwner() but it's the call to initModality() that seems to trigger the bug.  You can waste a lot of time playing with kludges that approximate the behavior you need but nothing seems to work just right.