# modal JavaFX stage initOwner prevents owner from resizing, bug?

Tags: java, javafx, resize

If I open another JavaFX (modal) `Stage`, and set its owner as the original `Stage`, then the original `Stage` can't be resized, using the windows drag widget on the bottom right hand corner of the window

I see this in Linux but don't own windows or MacOS so can't test it elsewhere...

here is a minimal example

```
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class HelloWorld extends Application
{
    static Stage newStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("open window");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                if (newStage==null)
                {
                    Button newBtn = new Button("Close window");
                    newBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                        {
                            //newStage.hide(); // either or
                            newStage.close();
                        }

                    });
                    newStage = new Stage();
                    newStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL); 
                    newStage.initOwner(primaryStage);    // BUG doing this, makes main window fixed size
                    newStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
                    StackPane newRoot = new StackPane();
                    newRoot.getChildren().add(newBtn);
                    Scene newScene = new Scene(newRoot,200,160);
                    newStage.setScene(newScene);

                }
                newStage.show();
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: as a point of clarification, the main window cannot be resized AFTER the secondary window is CLOSED....

Comment: JavaFX8, jdk1.8.0_73, Windows7 - no problems.

Comment: jdk18.0_92, Windows 7, no bug

Comment: did you try the sample above? were you able to resize the window AFTER you closed the second window?

Comment: Got the same bug on linux with 1.8.0_131. When switching to APPLICATION_MODAL, it even happens without setting the owner.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed Java bug. Looks like it's targeted for fixing in Java 10 sometime.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8140491

That said, I'd love a workaround if someone has one.

Edit: one workaround I've found, ugly as it is, is that you can hide and show the owner stage after hiding the modal child stage. That re-enables resizing. You see the stage disappear and reappear, though, which is messy.